# i am getting an error in this code but i dis find it

Tags: kotlin, android-music-player

```
val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0"
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
    val cursor = this.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + "DESC",null)///code at 126 line#
```

toggle.syncState()
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
MusicListMA = getAllAudio()
binding.musicrv.setHasFixedSize(true)//code at 111 line

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
intializeLayout()//code at 33line

this error i get

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hh, PID: 2858
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.h3mplayer/com.example.hh.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token date_addedDESC
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token date_addedDESC
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:472)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1183)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1115)
at com.example.h3mplayer.MainActivity.getAllAudio(MainActivity.kt:126)
at com.example.h3mplayer.MainActivity.intializeLayout(MainActivity.kt:110)
at com.example.h3mplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygot`your text`eInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clean-up your question a little bit? Things like formatting your code, stacktrace, fixing the typos and case in your title... You're asking people to spend some of their time thinking about your problem and helping you, so please try to make it as easy as possible for them to read your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Invalid token date_addedDESC

Consider adding a space between `date_added` and `DESC`, e.g.

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
```